# CMake with "standard" directory layout (Linux)

Tags: cmake

Let's say I have a simple hello project with the pseudo-standard directory layout

```
helloworld/
  src/
    main.c
    say.c
    say-helper.c
  include/
    say.h
    say-helper.h
  build/
```

and after running

```
cd ~/helloworld/build
cmake ..
make
```

I would expect the following

```
helloworld/
  build/lib/
    libsay.a
    libsay.so
    libsay.so.1.0.0
  tmp/obj/
    main.o
    say.o
  build/bin/
    hello
```

and after `make install` I would expect

```
/usr/local/lib/
  libsay.a
  libsay.so
  libsay.so.1.0.0
/usr/local/bin/
  hello
```

What would the `CMakeLists.txt` look like for this setup?

I've been looking around for examples, but the only one I've found that shows how to add a library and an executable didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basic commands to describe the project:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(include)
ADD_LIBRARY(say src/say.c src/say-helper.c)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(hello src/main.c)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(hello say)
```

This is for placing the libs and the executable in the build directory, put that in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
SET (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
SET (CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
SET (CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
```

For install you specify

```
 install(TARGETS say hello
            RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
            LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
            ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
```

in your CMakeLists.txt and set CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to /usr/local in your configuration.

I'm not sure if you can build static and dynamic libraries simultaneously with the same name, though. And I don't know how to tell CMake to put the obj files in some specific location.